# How do I run a program (specifically Eclipse) from a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, eclipse

I'm sick of doing `CTRL + ALT + T` then typing `cd ~/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse` and then `./eclipse` every time I want to open Eclipse, which is a lot.  I'm trying to setup a keyboard shortcut for it but I can't figure out what the correct command would be. I assumed it would be `eclipse /home/cschuck/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse` or `./eclipse /home/...` but nothing seems to work.

What command should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add eclipse to the beginning of your command. Just pointing it to the directory then the eclipse launcher will suffice.

`/home/cschuck/eclipse/java-neon/eclipse/eclipse`

will launch eclipse.

This is true of all scripts for example, if I have a file called `HelloWorld.sh` in `~/Documents/Scripts` it can be launched by simply typing `~/Documents/Scripts/HelloWorld.sh`